# How to setup Twilio queue for sending Whatsapp messages?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, queue, twilio, twilio-api

Basically the title.

Here's my project: I have a Python API running. Everytime a message reaches my number on Twilio (WhatsApp), the message goes to my API as a POST operation. Inside my API, once a few operations are finished, a message is sent back to the original Whatsapp number making the request, as a chatbot.

The thing is, I would like to make a queue, to ensure that once a user sends "message 1" and "message 2", "answer 2" reaches the user only once "answer1" is fully processed **(classic FIFO)**.

I was told that this was possible using only with Twilio Studio, but I just can't get it. I was thinking about an AWS SQS queue, with a trigger to a Lamda function that triggers my API. Good news is that this solution would not require changes on my original API code. Am I approaching this problem correctly?
Is It possible to implement this only with Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

These two suggestions sound right to me, either with Studio or your own app that manages a queue where you make sure to send answer1 before answer2 via the `client.messages.create` function. When sending replies with TwiML responses, the order is not guaranteed.